# What is the discretization method that the CART algorithm uses?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I'm currently working on a scikit-learn project and I was wondering how the decision tree algorihm used by the Classifier work. I try to understand how the tests on the nodes of the tree are chosen but I can't find any explanation on the method the algorithm uses to discretize continuous variable. I've read on a paper that some decision trees algorithm use the Tschuprow's T method but I'm not sure if CART is using it.
Does anybody know about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure, but I'd say CART evaluates all possible splits of a certain continuous variable according to the data. That is, if we have `X = {1, 3, 17, 24, 10005}` the split points would be `X < 1`, `X >= 1`, `X >= 3`, `X >= 17` and so on.

This is the only way to choose the best optimal split at each node, although it might be computationally expensive. If we explored only a subset of all the possible splits we might end up choosing a non-optimal (in a greedy sense) one.

Comment: Hey ! Thanks a lot, it helped me to understand the whole thing. Because this method is indeed computationally expensive, I thought there was another way to choose the best optimal split ... But how can we solve this problem about exploring only a subset of the splits? Is there a way to be sure to have the best optimal split among all the possible ones?

Comment: In order to be able to get the "best" optimal split among all the possible ones without testing all them you would probably need to use a heuristic or make assumptions regarding your data model. You can use continuous features discretization methods such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretization_of_continuous_features. Also, if your feature follows a normal distribution, you can test only for the 10 deciles cut points instead of all them.